# How to change Angular Material dialog container width size

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I wanted to changed the angular material dialog container width size. I have tried different approach even putting it on global style css and still it does not work.

Now what I am doing wrong ? why changed does not reflect ? does it have something to do with the default angular material ?

I also have tried adding it on my component css still same results.

Please bare with this one although this is not about problem solving or algorithms. Thank you.

## CSS

```
.mat-dialog-container { 
  display: block; 
  padding: 24px; 
  border-radius: 4px; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  overflow: auto; outline: 0; 
  /* width: 1800px !important; */ 
  height: 100%; min-height: inherit; 
  max-height: inherit; 
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 100vw !important;
}
```

[image: ma]

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
.cdk-overlay-pane {
pointer-events: auto;
box-sizing: border-box;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
width: 1005px !important; //your require width here
```

}